# Making order in Compas sprite image

Tags: image, sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to make some order in Compass sprite image. When I do in alphabetical order everything is fine

```
green.png (32x32px)
blue.png (32x32px)
red.png (32x32px)
```

when I put image with larger dimension like red.png (120x32px), red goes to top of the sprite.

```
red.png (120x32px)
green.png (32x32px)
blue.png (32x32px)
```

I've tried to use numbers but nothing. I need specific order because I call that sprite form external javascript file. How can I affect to sprite odrder?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining the `background-position` changes in JavaScript add or change the class.

Comment: I'm using for Google Maps and it is very complicated. I'm wondering is it Compass has solution for this.

Comment: Can you include a concrete example in your question? You may have [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: [Compass sprites layout](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/sprite-layouts/) this is the right example. Notice that the cloud is at first place on vertical layout because it is biggest img. My problem is similar i need vertical layout but need the cloud at the end of sprite. Is it possible to affect to image position in image

Comment: Nikola, I understand Compass sprites and problem you think you have. However, I am not convinced that you are trying to solve it in the best way. Instead of explaining your idea of a *solution*, explain the *problem*. In your project, what is the end product you want to have? What specifically are your trying to do with Google Maps?

Comment: As you wish :D. I'm creating some custom maps with different markers and I'm generating Compass sprite image for markers. Because I'm calling from javascript I need some ordered images array (alphabetical) in order to set position 
icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage("sprite.png", new google.maps.Size(16, 16), new google.maps.Point(0, cordinateVerticalShift)) }
How Am I Supposed to set coordinates if the Compass generate sprite based on file size :/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Compass can sort images in sprite only by file size, but I found that Compass will have ability to sort image by name in further versions

https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/commit/520c950f7d9a9bf7d5cf99842e898feec8aa7364

Answer (score 0):

Use the horizontal layout mode:

```
  $YOURMAP-layout: horizontal;
```

This mode doesn't use file size to order images as other modes do.

Also see
https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1002